# Artinian property of local cohomology module over graded local ring

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, cohomology

We know that if $(R, m)$ is a local ring, $M$ is a finitely generated $R$-module, then the local cohomology module $H^{i}_{m}(M)$ is an Artinian module for every $j$.

My question is : if $(R,m)$ is a graded local ring, then is $H^{i}_{m}(M)$ is an Artinian module for every $j$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this even holds for non-graded rings.  Indeed, suppose that $R$ is a (Noetherian?) ring and $m \subseteq R$ is a maximal ideal.

Then
$$
H^i_m(M) = H^i_{mR_m}(M_m)
$$
essentially by Chapter III, Exercise 2.3(f) (excision) of Hartshorne.

Also note that $N \subseteq H^i_{mR_m}(M_m)$ is an $R$-submodule if and only if it is an $R_m$-module.